# issue downloading Vue-chart.js chart as a PNG

Tags: charts, vue-chartjs, nuxt3

I cannot get a my vue-chart.js canvas to download using toDataURL() I have tried multiple methods with no success and continue to run into a tainted canvas error wondering if anyone else has had this issue?

[image: picture of error]

Below is the example of the code which gets the canvas from the "copyChart" ref which is assigned to the line graph  and returns the canvas as a PNG.

```
const copyChart = ref(null);

function downloadChart() {
  const imageLink = document.createElement("a");
  const canvas = copyChart.value.chart.canvas;
  imageLink.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
}
```

and here is the code that generates the line graph

```
     <div>
        <Line
          ref="copyChart"
          id="my-chart-id"
          :options="options"
          :data="mainData"
        />
    </div>
```

Regarding the framework I am currently using Nuxt3